# Purge messages that contain a certain string discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm new to javascript and have reccently been tinkering around with the discord API called [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/). I would like to make a command in my bot that can purge all the messages in a channel, **unless** it includes a certian string or emoji, **and** it is written by a certian person. Does anyone know how I could go about doing this? I have taken a look at the [`.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) method, but there is no way to tell it not to delete some messages that include a certian string.

EDIT: I have seen this post: [Search a given discord channel for all messages that satisfies the condition and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819979/search-a-given-discord-channel-for-all-messages-that-satisfies-the-condition-and), but it does the opposite of what I want; that post is if there is a certian keyword in the message, it gets deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's work our way to a solution step by step.

1. To gather a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message)s from a channel, use the [`TextBasedChannel.fetchMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages) method.
2. With [`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter), you can return only the elements from a Collection that meet certain conditions.
3. You can check if a message contains a string in a variety of ways, but perhaps the simplest is the combination of [`Message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) and [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).
4. The sender of a message can be referenced via the [`Message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) property. To check the author against another user, you should compare their IDs, returned by [`User.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id).
5. In the filter method's predicate function, "unless" would translate to the [logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), `!`. We can place it before a set of conditions so that if they *are* met, the operator will return `false`. That way, messages that *don't* meet your specified constrains will be *excluded* from the returned Collection.

Tying this together so far...

```js
channel.fetchMessages(...)
  .then(fetchedMessages => {
    const messagesToDelete = fetchedMessages.filter(msg => !(msg.author.id === 'someID' && msg.content.includes('keep')));
    ...
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

6. To bulk delete messages, you can use the [`TextChannel.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) method, as you have discovered.
7. After the correct messages have been deleted, you can add a response if you wish, employing [`TextBasedChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send).

Altogether...

```js
// Depending on your use case...
// const channel = message.channel;
// const channel = client.channels.get('someID');

channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 100 })
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^
// You can only bulk delete up to 100 messages per call.
  .then(fetchedMessages => {
    const messagesToDelete = fetchedMessages.filter(msg => !(msg.author.id === 'someID' && msg.content.includes('keep')));

    return channel.bulkDelete(messagesToDelete, true);
//                                              ^^^^
//        The second parameter here represents whether or not to automatically skip messages
//               that are too old to delete (14 days old) due to API restrictions.
  })
  .then(deletedMessages => channel.send(`Deleted **${deletedMessages.size}** message${deletedMessages.size !== 1 ? 's' : ''}.`))
//                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                                                This template literal will add an 's' if the word 'message' should be plural.
  .catch(console.error);
```

---

*To maintain better flow of your code, consider using [async/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm going to try this right now.